# Protecting IP address through FTP client

Tags: ftp, ip

Do FTP clients (like Filezilla for example) expose my IP address to webhosting services while uploading/downloading files from their server?

If yes, then are there any FTP clients out there that can conceal my IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need an IP address in order to access any server. It's fundamental property of the internet.

Use a service like DynDNS or No-IP. But even then, you can't hide your IP, just cloak it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. If you directly make contact with any server, your IP address will always be "exposed".
One option would be to connect indirectly (through a proxy for example), in that case the server you are contacting will see the proxy server's IP address.

Comment: ok, so I would have to use something like TOR inorder to upload files through the "File Manager" of my webhosting service, am i right?

Comment: Connecting with the FTP server over TOR is an option indeed. I believe Filezilla can be configured to use a SOCKS proxy.